# Scala's own LLVM implementation

Tags: scala, vm-implementation

I am reading up on the LLVM and trying to learn compiler design. My question is: if there is any plan for any dedicated Scala runtime, with Byte code portability on other runtimes like JVM, .net

Also are there any existing LLVM implementations for the same.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you a) asking about Scala bindings for LLVM, so that you could e.g. write a compiler or an optimization pass in Scala, b) asking about a Scala implementation targeting and/or using LLVM, c) a portable bytecode format for Scala?

Comment: Hi @JörgWMittag , my question is around the first 2 points that you have raised , a bit clear about the bytecode portability now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Scala Native](https://github.com/scala-native/scala-native) was open sourced at NYC ScalaDays yesterday.

> Scala Native is a new ahead-of-time compiler and lightweight managed runtime designed specifically for Scala
>
> Scala Native is compiled ahead-of-time via LLVM

Answer (score 4):

There is a discontinued .NET backend, and a [JS backend](http://www.scala-js.org/). Typesafe is understandably focusing on the JVM. So go for it.

Studying the scala.js compiler should be quite helpful. One thing worth noting is that scala.js does not support java or scala reflection, but it nevertheless manages to support a large number of popular scala libraries. This is due to the fact that reflection is not as common in scala libraries than in java libraries.

Answer (score 4):

Note that there is an old unfinished try for llvm: https://github.com/greedy/scala

It seems by [this thread](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2015-February/082875.html) that some research in scala <---> llvm is starting or already going on. But don't expect anything about this soon.